# OpenCL and clBlas: how to perform multiple matrix-matrix multiplications

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, opencl, gpu

I am new to OpenCL and especially to clBlas. I would like to implement a simple program that takes as input a matrix A, multiplies it with another matrix B obtaining a matrix C, then multiplies C for another matrix D, and returns the result matrix of these operations.

I would like to do it deploying the clBlas library, trying to keep the maximum performance. How can I do it?

So far I have seen that the common way of doing a single matrix multiplication is the following:

```
/* Setup clBLAS */
err = clblasSetup( );

/* Prepare OpenCL memory objects and place matrices inside them. */
bufA = clCreateBuffer( ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, M * K * sizeof(*A),
                      NULL, &err );
bufB = clCreateBuffer( ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, K * N * sizeof(*B),
                      NULL, &err );
bufC = clCreateBuffer( ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, M * N * sizeof(*C),
                      NULL, &err );

err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( queue, bufA, CL_TRUE, 0,
    M * K * sizeof( *A ), A, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( queue, bufB, CL_TRUE, 0,
    K * N * sizeof( *B ), B, 0, NULL, NULL );
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer( queue, bufC, CL_TRUE, 0,
    M * N * sizeof( *C ), C, 0, NULL, NULL );

    /* Call clBLAS extended function. Perform gemm for the lower right sub-matrices */
    err = clblasSgemm( clblasRowMajor, clblasNoTrans, clblasNoTrans,
                            M, N, K,
                            alpha, bufA, 0, lda,
                            bufB, 0, ldb, beta,
                            bufC, 0, ldc,
                            1, &queue, 0, NULL, &event );

/* Wait for calculations to be finished. */
err = clWaitForEvents( 1, &event );

/* Fetch results of calculations from GPU memory. */
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( queue, bufC, CL_TRUE, 0,
                            M * N * sizeof(*result),
                            result, 0, NULL, NULL );
```

But in this way we are keeping moving the matrices from the host memory to the GPU memory at this is a waste, is there a way of maintaining the result in the GPU memory?

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I have edited my question

Comment: Omit the intermediate `clEnqueueReadBuffer( ..., bufC, ..., resA, ... )` and `clEnqueueWriteBuffer( ..., resA, ... )`, use `bufC` again as an input parameter?

Comment: Aside: you are ignoring the value of `err`? Either handle errors or don't bother assigning it

Comment: @Caleth, so even if I don't read the value of the buffer containing bufC will it be updated in the GPU memory? Oh and I removed all the checks on err to keep the code short here on stackOverflow!! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why would the data in bufC be modified and not bufA or bufB? None of them are modified unless you modify them.

Comment: Remember you will also have to release your buffers. I suggest wrapping them in a move-only class that calls `clReleaseMemObject` in it's destructor. Something like `struct cl_deleter{ void operator()(cl_mem obj){ clReleaseMemObject(obj); } }; using cl_ptr = std::unique_ptr<_cl_mem, cl_deleter>;`